# Is this method of initialization recommended?

Tags: java

So when I was coding my own project, a problem came up with initializing an object. My class has so many attributes that needs to be initiated BUT not always all of them, which . That's when I came up with this idea (but I'm not sure if it's used before anywhere):

```
public class MyClass {
    public static final int DEFAULT1 = 1;
    public static final int DEFAULT2 = 2;
    public static final int DEFAULT3 = 3;
    private int attr1;
    private int attr2;
    private int attr3;
    private MyClass(){
        attr1 = DEFAULT1;
        attr2 = DEFAULT2;
        attr3 = DEFAULT3;
    }
    public static MyClass create(){
        return new MyClass();
    }
    public MyClass setAttr1(int attr1){
        this.attr1 = attr1;
        return this;
    }
    public MyClass setAttr2(int attr2){
        this.attr2 = attr2;
        return this;
    }
    public MyClass setAttr3(int attr3){
        this.attr3 = attr3;
        return this;
    }
}
```

When I create a new `MyClass` instance I would do:

```
MyClass obj = MyClass.create().setAttr1(3).setAttr3(1);
```

It worked for me (kind of because I tested it but I haven't decided to use it in my project). My question is, is this legit? Would it create any kinds of memory/execution problems?

Comment: use builder design pattern, if you have some optional properties read more https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/builder_pattern.htm , which is the recommended way of creating objects and it suits specifically in your case.

Comment: Oh right, thank you for pointing that out. I didn't know there was a whole design pattern for this haha.

Comment: This is very close to the Builder design pattern already, as discussed by @AmitK above. To get it all the way there, move out the `setAttr*` methods to another class called `MyClassBuilder`, where they'd return the current `MyClassBuilder` object to aid chaining. Finally, there should be an instance method `build` which creates a `MyClass` object with the attributes just set and returns it (you might want to put these classes into a separate package and use package-private (default) visibility for your fields, if necessary).

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury , thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use case is a perfect example of `Builder` design pattern. Read more about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) and [oracle doc about builder](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-982813#Builder). Also read why `Builder` pattern has an advantage over other creation pattern by Java legend `Joshua` which is discuss in his book, best practice of java 
 [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2).

Your converted class using `Builder` design pattern will look like below. Note that i assumed `attr1` optional and `attr2` and `attr3` as mandatory.

```
class MyClass {
    public static final int DEFAULT1 = 1;
    public static final int DEFAULT2 = 2;
    public static final int DEFAULT3 = 3;

    // assume attr1 is optional
    private int attr1;
    // assume attr2,3 is mandatory
    private int attr2;
    private int attr3;


    public MyClass(MyClassBuilder myClassBuilder) {
        this.attr1 = myClassBuilder.attr1;
        this.attr2 = myClassBuilder.attr2;
        this.attr3 = myClassBuilder.attr3;
    }

    //Builder Class
    public static class MyClassBuilder {

        // required parameters
        private int attr2;
        private int attr3;
        // optional parameters
        private int attr1;

        public MyClassBuilder(int attr2, int attr3){
            this.attr2 = attr2;
            this.attr3 = attr3;
        }

        public MyClassBuilder setAttr1(int attr1) {
            this.attr1 = attr1;
            return this;
        }


        public MyClass build(){
            return new MyClass(this);
        }

    }

}
```

Now After that using below code, you can create the objects (with/without) optional param.

```
public class MyClassTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass.MyClassBuilder(10,20).build();
    // without optional param
    System.out.println("without optional param");
    System.out.println("attr1 "+ myClass.getAttr1());
    System.out.println("attr2 "+ myClass.getAttr2());
    System.out.println("attr3 "+ myClass.getAttr3());

    // with optional param
    System.out.println("with optional param");
    MyClass myClassWithAllParam = new MyClass.MyClassBuilder(10,20).setAttr1(5).build();
    System.out.println("attr1 "+ myClassWithAllParam.getAttr1());
    System.out.println("attr2 "+ myClassWithAllParam.getAttr2());
    System.out.println("attr3 "+ myClassWithAllParam.getAttr3());

    }
}
```

Output of which is below :-

```
without optional param
attr1 0
attr2 10
attr3 20
with optional param
attr1 5
attr2 10
attr3 20
```

Comment: Very specific examples. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Another name for it is [Fluent Interface](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

You just need to use `with` instead of `set` for method names. The `set` naming is kind of reserved for JavaBeans convention.